# Displaying the inside of a building on a mobile

Tags: java, android

I'm not sure where to start or what to search for, but how would i display a map of the inside of one building. The display is to be shown on a mobile phone as an app.
I have hand drawn the inside of the building but what software would i use to create it on my mobile?

Comment: You are going to want to be WAY more specific if you want good help.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked a very general question, so the best I can do is give you a general answer. You're doing this for a single building, so I'm assuming you'll have the map of the building before hand. If it's just an image, you should be able to display the image of the map in an [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html).

Comment: I think he wants to navigate the building using the phone? Sort of how you can navigate street view?? I imagine he should be going towards the OpenGL graphics if this is the case.